# ios translate3d animation creating "padding"

Tags: ios, css, safari

An element has the CSS Properties:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);
transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0);

-webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
transition: all 250ms ease;
```

The element (in JS) is then given the following inline properties:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 1000px, 0);
-ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 1000px, 0);
transform: translate3d(0px, 1000px, 0);
```

1000px is the height of the container so that the element is hidden. In JS it is then stripped of it's inline properties so that the browser animates it back into position 0px; This works as expected on all browsers.

However on the latest version of iOS the container has random space beneath the element that matches what it once had as a property for transform. e.g. 1000px of 'padding' which only disappears if you remove the transform property from the css altogether (i.e. put it in a separate class then remove that class after the animation) however you then get a flicker on the screen (Which can be fixed by adding the translate3d 0px property - but i'm left with random space!

Can't replicate this on desktop or android and I can't find anyone else talking about this issue online.

Here's an example: http://tinyurl.com/pdfndrd

Comment: Did you figure out why this is happening?

Comment: @arao6 I put it down to being a bug in the end - I can't remember how I overcame the problem though sorry.